# How to set the SQS message class in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, amazon-sqs

I'm migrating from boto to boto3.

The following snippet sets the message class to my sqs:

```
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(my_region)
queue = conn.create_queue(queue_name)
queue.set_message_class(boto.sqs.message.RawMessage)
```

How to do this with boto3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `SQS Client` and use it. You don't need to set `RawMessage` class anymore.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sqs')
response = client.send_message(
    QueueUrl='string',
    MessageBody='string',
    DelaySeconds=123,
    MessageAttributes={
        'string': {
            'StringValue': 'string',
            'BinaryValue': b'bytes',
            'StringListValues': [
                'string',
            ],
            'BinaryListValues': [
                b'bytes',
            ],
            'DataType': 'string'
        }
    },
    MessageDeduplicationId='string',
    MessageGroupId='string'
)
```

Source: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.send_message

Comment: Thankyou @Asdfg, this is the correct answer. As you pointed out, setting the RawMessage class isn't mentioned anywhere, so I deduce that I can skip this step.